# Creating new divs using loop, appending child nodes on each new div

Tags: javascript, html, loops, dom

I am working on an assignment for one of my classes, and I need help with the following:

Using Javascript, I must create divs for every book (50 total, example of one below) in a JSON object, and place the image, title, and description of each book inside the newly created divs.

Here is the example of one of the books in the object:

```
var itunesResponse = {
  "results": [
    {
      "fileSizeBytes": 468847,
      "artistViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/artist\/brad-land\/5526375?mt=11&uo=4",
      "trackCensoredName": "Goat",
      "trackViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/book\/goat\/id420798692?mt=11&uo=4",
      "artworkUrl60": "http:\/\/is4.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Publication18\/v4\/1c\/48\/62\/1c4862bd-1a5d-0a7c-7143-2878aed682f8\/source\/60x60bb.jpg",
      "artworkUrl100": "http:\/\/is4.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Publication18\/v4\/1c\/48\/62\/1c4862bd-1a5d-0a7c-7143-2878aed682f8\/source\/100x100bb.jpg",
      "currency": "USD",
      "artistId": 5526375,
      "artistName": "Brad Land",
      "genres": [
        "Biographies & Memoirs",
        "Books",
        "Professional & Technical",
        "Education",
        "Nonfiction",
        "Social Science"
      ],
      "kind": "ebook",
      "price": 9.99,
      "description": "<b>Soon to be a major motion picture starring Nick Jonas, this&#xa0;searing memoir of fraternity culture and the perils of hazing&#xa0;provides an unprecedented window&#xa0;into the emotional landscape of young men.<\/b><br \/><br \/>Reeling from a terrifying assault that has left him physically injured and psychologically shattered, nineteen-year-old Brad Land must also contend with unsympathetic local police, parents who can barely discuss \u201cthe incident\u201d (as they call it), a brother riddled with guilt but unable to slow down enough for Brad to keep up, and the feeling that he\u2019ll never be normal again.<br \/><br \/>When Brad\u2019s brother enrolls at Clemson University and pledges a fraternity, Brad believes he\u2019s being left behind once and for all. Desperate to belong, he follows. What happens there\u2014in the name of \u201cbrotherhood,\u201d and with the supposed goal of forging a scholar and a gentleman from the raw materials of boyhood\u2014involves torturous late-night hazing, heartbreaking estrangement from his brother, and, finally, the death of a fellow pledge. Ultimately, Brad must weigh total alienation from his newfound community against accepting a form of brutality he already knows too well.<br \/><br \/><i>From the Hardcover edition.<\/i>",
      "formattedPrice": "$9.99",
      "artistIds": [
        5526375
      ],
      "genreIds": [
        "9008",
        "38",
        "9029",
        "10037",
        "9002",
        "10120"
      ],
      "releaseDate": "2004-02-03T08:00:00Z",
      "trackId": 420798692,
      "trackName": "Goat",
      "userRatingCount": 16,
      "averageUserRating": 3.5
    }
  ]
}
```

I plan on creating everything using a loop, but every time I try to append a heading (for the title) into the new div via a loop, everything just ends up in the last-created div.

My recently attempted code:

```
let body = document.getElementById('wrapper');
let newImg = document.createElement('img');
let newTit = document.createElement('h3');
let newDes = document.createElement('p');
        for(i=0; i<itunesResponse.results.length; i++ ){
            let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
            body.appendChild(newDiv);
            newDiv.appendChild(newTit);
            newDiv.style.color = 'rgb(100,100,100)';
            let titVal = document.createTextNode(itunesResponse.results[i].trackName);
            newTit.appendChild(titVal);
        }
```

Comment: Can't you assign an ID to divs to distinguish them?

Comment: or create the div AND populate its content before putting the div in the DOM ?

Comment: Please show your attempted code and let us know what specifically goes wrong.

Comment: I tried assigning IDs to the divs to distinguish them, but I still have issues trying to append the titles into every single one of them.

Comment: I also tried populating, but it still goes to the last div.

Comment: `I tried assigning IDs to the divs to distinguish them` - please post what you have tried

Comment: change `for(i=0; i<itunesResponse.results.length; i++ )` to `for(let i=0; i<itunesResponse.results.length; i++ )` and the same in the second loop. i guess this is why it ends up in the last `div`

Comment: Is there a reason that you are looping over the same array multiple times? Did you verify that your book `div`s are being added into the DOM? I don't see them being appended anywhere in your example

Comment: I see a syntax error in the definition : `var = itunesResponse = {'results' = [`.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel i also needed some time to see the appending but `extDiv[l].appendChild(newTit);` adds something, but you are right `newDiv` seems to be appended never

Comment: Here's my previous attempt. Everything all goes to a newly-created heading.

Comment: You keep re-using the same `newTit` variable. Did you try creating a new one in your loop each time?

Comment: Also, the reason for looping is so I can get all the data from the itunesResponse array into each div every time it's created

Comment: I am trying to create it each time and append it into the new div.

Comment: In your example you are creating outside of the loop and then keep using it within your loop

Comment: So, how do I create a new heading within the new div and loop it?

Comment: move the creation of it to inside the loop

Comment: That worked. Every div has a new title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to append the new div to the DOM and move the creation of the new title to inside the loop.

```
let body = document.getElementById('wrapper');

for (let i = 0; i < itunesResponse.results.length; i++) {
    let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.style.color = 'rgb(100,100,100)';
    body.appendChild(newDiv);

    let newTit = document.createElement('h3');
    newDiv.appendChild(newTit);

    let titVal = document.createTextNode(itunesResponse.results[i].trackName);
    newTit.appendChild(titVal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a syntax error in your definition of `itunesResponse`, corrected below.
Also you'll want to create new elements for each entry, inside the loop.

```js
var itunesResponse = {
  "results": [{
      "trackName": "Goat"
    },
    {
      "trackName": "Another Track"
    }
  ]
};

let body = document.getElementById('wrapper');

for (i = 0; i < itunesResponse.results.length; i++) {
  let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  let newTit = document.createElement('h3');
  body.appendChild(newDiv);
  newDiv.appendChild(newTit);
  newDiv.style.color = 'rgb(100,100,100)';
  let titVal = document.createTextNode(itunesResponse.results[i].trackName);
  newTit.appendChild(titVal);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

make the variables declaration inside the the loop you can leave the body out of the loop although it isn't the best way to do what need